How to communicate to the epec controller via ros or ros2 framework?
Currently I have used an epec5050 controller to control the hub motor, how do I connect the host computer to communicate to the epec5050 controller via ros or ros2 framework to control the hub motor?

Easiest way to do it is : Develop a a ROS 2 node that can send and receive messages to and from the Epec 5050 controller.
Connect it physically to your computer with Ethernet or use CAN to receive and send messages , you may need can adapter to connect it to you personal pc
